# Update Redux store for every character entered in a input field?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a sequential data collection app built with React and Redux. Right now, I have internal state for each page which has a form and when user clicks "Submit" button, I am dispatching the data collected in the state and updating my Redux store. Should I be dispatching an action on every key entered(debouncing) or should I store it in a local state and update Redux store at once?

Will there be a performance issue if I dispatch action to Redux store on every keypress since it is not an asynchronous call.

Comment: Can you give some use cases?

If you're using a form then you could store it in redux on submit or if they take some action to move away from the page...as in to hold the data they did fill out but not submitted.

Comment: `Should I be dispatching an action on every key entered(debouncing) ?` NO.INstead for this collcted form data

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is: it depends.

Some argue that we loose some of the advantages of using a central store (like Redux) if you also have an internal state in the components. Like, if all your application state is just the redux store, storing the store, or the sequence of actions that lead to that store, will give you a complete picture of what was happening before maybe an error occurs.

I believe that is excessive. It is completely fine to store little stuff in your component's internal state, but there should be a well defined line.

In case of a form, you'd have controlled input elements, and you'll want a mechanism to submit the form with an action. It'd be necessary to have the contents of the form in the redux store.

One way would be to have the contents in an internal state, and only put them into redux form after a little debounce. But that has some edge cases. What if the user submits the form in the little debounce time? The form in the store is incomplete. Is thinking about all the edge cases worth it?

I believe just having the form elements controlled from the redux form is the simplest solution. The performance issue one would imagine is not really an issue. This is also what [`redux-form`](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/) does (you can look at how that is implemented for inspiration).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My app has data collection form, which is very long. Assume I have 30 fields like inputs, text areas, selects etc., on a page. If I store in an internal state, what if the user clicks browser 'Refresh' button? All the data would be lost. So I was thinking to update Redux and save my store in localStorage.

Comment: I'd recommend you use a mature library to handle such a form (redux-form is good). You can use something like redux-persist to persist the store (or parts of it) so that you don't loose incomplete form data.